# Postgresql compare consecutive rows and insert identical row if there are no values

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, rank

I have a table that gives me data every 15 minute and I need that range of time.
I noticed that sometimes I don't have data for 3/4 hours but I need to duplicate the last row available with the missing timestamp.

Example:

| product_id | total_revenue | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 01-01-2021 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 17 | 01-01-2021 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 30 | 01-01-2021 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 67 | 01-01-2021 00:15:00 |
| 2 | 31 | 01-01-2021 00:15:00 |
| 1 | 67 | 01-01-2021 00:30:00 |
| 2 | 31 | 01-01-2021 00:30:00 |
| 3 | 33 | 01-01-2021 00:30:00 |

But I need an output like:

| product_id | total_revenue | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 01-01-2021 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 17 | 01-01-2021 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 30 | 01-01-2021 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 67 | 01-01-2021 00:15:00 |
| 2 | 31 | 01-01-2021 00:15:00 |
| 3 | 30 | 01-01-2021 00:15:00 |
| 1 | 67 | 01-01-2021 00:30:00 |
| 2 | 31 | 01-01-2021 00:30:00 |
| 3 | 33 | 01-01-2021 00:30:00 |

I have a select statement like:

select product_id,total_revenue,timestamp
from revenue

(I calculate the difference between two consecutive rows too).

Does anybody know how to help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses `generate_series()` and `lead()`:

```
with tt as (
      select product_id, total_revenue, timestamp,
             lead(timestamp) over (partition by product_id order by timestamp) as next_timestamp
      from t
     )
select tt.product_id, coalesce(gs.ts, tt.timestamp),
       tt.total_revenue
from tt left join lateral
     generate_series(timestamp, next_timestamp - interval '15 minute', interval '15 minute') gs(ts);
```

Note:  My guess is that you also want this extended to the most recent timestamp in the table:

```
with tt as (
      select product_id, total_revenue, timestamp,
             lead(timestamp) over (partition by product_id order by timestamp) as next_timestamp,
             max(timestamp) over () as max_timestamp
      from t
     )
select tt.product_id, coalesce(gs.ts, tt.timestamp),
       tt.total_revenue
from tt left join lateral
     generate_series(timestamp,
                     coalesce(next_timestamp - interval '15 minute', max_timestamp),
                     interval '15 minute'
                    ) gs(ts);
```

Also, if the timestamps are not exactly at 15 minute intervals, then I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with explanation and more realistic sample data.